# RailsAdmin filter by certain fields only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Is that possible to configure rails admin to filter by certain field only, as right now it can search by all of the column and it is slow.

[image]

Apparently my add filter button didn't show up the fields as well after I customize the index page. Here's my setting under my model file:

[image]

```
rails_admin do |config|
  list do
    field :application_id 
    field :release_date
    field :title
    field :detail

    sort_by :release_date
    sort_reverse true
  end
end
```

How do I customise to search by certain field only and customise add filter options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List) says we can turn off searching on certain fields with

```
field :created_at do
  searchable false
end
```

You can configure the options for filters, but it seems to accept only an array of fields:

```
filters [:name, :manager]
```

Comment: Well, the RailsAdmin docs are pretty verbose and not all that well organized. Also, they can't be counted on to be 100% up to date. :)

Comment: I want to search specific fields only how to do that? 
Eg: column1…column50. Should search column2, column3 instead of 50columns . So I can improve performance.